# DLink 3G router strange behavior

Tags: router, 3g

I have a DLink 3G router DWR-112. After unboxing, I plugged the LAN cable, switched on the router, plugged my 3G EVO usb device, add user/pw and other details everythings works perfectly and I was able to access internet both via LAN and Wifi.

Next morning when I checked my device 3G light was off, I checked my evo-device directly using my PC it was working. I again plugged the 3G evo-device to router but it did not work at all. Then I switched off then on my router. Now both 3G light signal and wifi signal went off.

What's going on? I switched off/on a couple of times then device started working perfectly.

Is my device faulty?

Answer (score 2):

NO your device is not having any problem, actually DW112 takes 10 to 15 minutes to be in working state again ( 3G internet ) if it is powered off, so when ever you r going to power it on you need to wait at least for 10 minutes, it will be configured again automatically.